# Корректный конфиг для мульти-язычного сайта

Tags: nginx

Как корректно написать конфиг для мульти-язычногого сайта? Правильно делать несколько блоков с редиректами с www или есть более компактный вариант в одном блоке как с основными доменами? В официальной документации не нашёл...

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    domain.com default;
    domain.ru russian;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.domain.ru;
    return 301 $scheme://domain.ru$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com domain.ru;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/domain.com/html;
    set $MAGE_MODE default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте 2 секции server, если конфиги сильно разнятся для доменов (по одной для каждого домена), или одну секцию для обоих доменов, если настройки схожие (как сейчас). Для одной секции необходимо использовать внутренние переменные.

Редиректы с www используются нормально. Использование нескольких блоков с редиректами в Вашем случае разумно. Заменил бы $scheme на http.

Про использование переменных тяжело что-то сказать - мало информации.
Резюме - конфиг рабочий.